# How to get object from list by type

Tags: java, collections, types

I have several classes and some list:

```
A
B : A
C : A
D : A
...
SomeList<A> list
```

By C# I can get required object by type with something like this:

```
public T getObject <T> () where T : A {
    return (T)objects[typeof(T)];
}

public A objects [Type _type] {
    get {
        var temp = from _a in _list where _a.GetType() == _type select _a;
        return temp.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

How to get it with java?

Comment: Your \*Java\* snippet does not tell us much about what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: I believe you'd have to iterate the list and inspect the `instanceof` each element and build a new List for your sub-type.

Comment: You could pass in the class of the type you are trying to cast and use reflection.

Comment: If flexible for changing from `List` to `Map`, you can do a `Map` with key of object type and value a list of the objects of that type. Retrieving the same type will become easy this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know C#.  However, in Java, if you have a map and you wish to collect a single object of a given type which is retrieval by type you might do the following:

```
Map byType = new HashMap<Class<A>, A>();

void insertObject(Object v) {
   byType.put(v.getClass(), v);
}

Object getObject(Class c) {
    return byType.get(c);
}
```

Of course, you can only store a single object of a given type (class).   If you want to store more than one object of a given type, you might want to use a muitimap.  There are a number of libraries which include such a collection such as org.apache.commons.collections, google's guava (com.google.common.collect), etc.

HTH

-steve

Answer (score 1):

In Java you would do it like this:

```
public <T> T getObjectByType(Class<T> cl) {
    for (Object item : _list) {
        cl.isInstance(item) {
            return (T)item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
B b = someList.getObjectByType<B>(B.class);
```

You can do it the same way in C#, too, but LINQ makes it simpler.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl You're right. I also removed `A` form the method, replacing with `Object`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the possible types of the object you can use the

> instanceof

operator.For example :

```
SomeList<A> list;
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    if( list.get(i) instanceof  AClass){
       .....
    }else if(list.get(i) instanceof BClass){
      .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instanceof` in java to check object type.

```
for (T x : list) {
   if (T instanceof MyClass) {
     // Do your stuff...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use instanceOf in Java like this.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        /*
         * List of A object
         */
        List<A> objectList = new ArrayList();

        /*
         * Adding object to the list
         */
        objectList.add(new A());
        objectList.add(new B());
        objectList.add(new B());

        /*
         * Iterate through list and display object's type
         */
        for(A a : objectList) {
            if(a instanceof A) {
                System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
            }
            if(a instanceof B) {
                System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
            }
        }

    }

    /*
     * 
     */
    static class A {

    }

    static class B extends A {

    }

    static class C extends A {

    }
}
```